# DocumentBeforePrint and WordWebbAddIn

Tags: office-js

I have a C# Word AddIn where I have code behind the DocumentBeforePrint event. I'm now looking at the new WordWebAddIn technology and have failed to work out how to intercept the print action?

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Martin

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately we don't support that event yet. I recommend voting for this feature https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

thanks!